# Pinging Websocket server with Websocket .NET client

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket

I'm trying to figure out how to send `ping`/`pong` heartbeats in order to be sure to maintain a connection with a Websocket server using [Websocket .NET client](https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client) in a .NET Core WPF Application, so I'm testing with [this Binance Websocket](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#websocket-market-streams) which says

> The websocket server will send a `ping frame` every 3 minutes. If the websocket server does not receive a `pong frame` back from the connection within a 10 minute period, the connection will be disconnected. Unsolicited `pong frames` are allowed.

However, when I try to connect using my sample code, I simply never receive any message from the websocket that contains the string `ping`, and the connection seems to never fail if there is at least one stream subscribed to. Also sending unsolicited `pong` messages seems to always throw an  `error 3: invalid JSON` followed by a disconnection.

<strike>Are `ping`/`pong` heartbeats managed by the NuGet Package *(even though I didn't find any line that mentions `ping` or `pong` in its source code)*, or simply doesn't support them? If so then how/why is my connection to Binance Websocket not getting disconnected?</strike>

Here's my sample code for the `WSClient` class so you can try and see that you won't get disconnected even after +15mins:

**Update:** It's handled internally by the `WebsocketClient`, and the `KeepAliveInterval` is actually sending `pong` frames each interval. I wonder though if it's possible to subscribe some event to see when these frames are being sent, which could be useful when dealing with strict messages rates limitations to not get accidently disconnected when sending the max number of messages at the same time as the pong frame is being sent.

```
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using Websocket.Client;
using Websocket.Client.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class WSClient
{
    private List<string> logs = new List<string>();

    private WebsocketClient client;
    private string wsUrl = "wss://stream.binance.com/ws";
    
    public WSClient() { }

    public async Task InitializeClient()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(wsUrl);
        Func<ClientWebSocket> factory = new Func<ClientWebSocket>(() => {
            ClientWebSocket wsClient = new ClientWebSocket
            {
                Options =
                {
                    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) // interval to send pong frames             }
            };

            return wsClient;
        });

        client = new WebsocketClient(uri, factory);
        client.Name = "WebsocketClient";
        client.ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        client.ErrorReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

        client.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(OnReconnection);
        client.DisconnectionHappened.Subscribe(OnDisconnect);

        client.MessageReceived
            .Where((ResponseMessage message) => message.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            .Subscribe(OnMessage);

        try
        {
            await client.StartOrFail();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logs.Add($"Error: { ex.Message }");
        }

        // Subscribing to a stream (btcusdt@aggTrade for example)
        client.Send("{\"method\": \"SUBSCRIBE\",\"params\":[\"btcusdt@aggTrade\"],\"id\": 1}");
    }

    private void OnReconnection(ReconnectionInfo info)
    {
        logs.Add("Reconnected");
    }

    private void OnMessage(ResponseMessage message)
    {
        logs.Add(message.Text);
    }

    private void OnDisconnect(DisconnectionInfo info)
    {
        logs.Add("Diconnected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help debug.  Check body of response to see what the string actually looks like. Http uses TCP as the transport layer.  Normal TCP Keep-Alive sends an packet with no data for the Keep-Alive.  Have not looked at the Github code to see what actually is being used.

Comment: @jdweng I tried to use wireshark but weirdly enough, the received messages are not captured using `Websocket` protocol, but `TLSv1.2` instead. I couldn't read any meaning information besides that.

Comment: HTTP protocol (websocket) will will not occur until the TLS validates.  So you are probably seeing the TLS Authentication occurring, but failing.  So the server may want TLS 1.3 instead of 1.2.  Or the certificate is not probably loading or wrong encryption mode is being used.   There doesn't appear to be any TLS options in your client.  So it must be defaulting to the operating system (or kernel).  So what version of core are you using.  What kernel are you using for the machine?

Comment: @jdweng I'm currently on **Windows 10** _(version 1903)_ using **.NET Core 3.1**. The most interesting part is that I still can receive functional data using that c# client. I also tried with two other similar Websocket servers _([Bitmex](https://www.bitmex.com/app/wsAPI) and [Bitfinex](https://docs.bitfinex.com/docs/ws-general))_ and they both also appear in wireshark only sending `TLSv1.2` packets. These servers however do not require to send `ping`/`pong` raw frames which is necessary for the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `WebSocketClient` is handling the ping-pong protocol under the covers. I believe you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: You are right, after investigating further in the source code, it's automatically responding to each ping frame with a pong. Also, the `ClientWebSocket`'s `KeepAliveInterval` option is actually sending a pong frame each interval, not just basic TCP KeepAlive.

Comment: The problem with `ClientWebSocket` is, that it only send pong (not ping) and don't wait for response. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48729

Comment: If you want to detect quickly problematic connection (and want to use `ClientWebSocket`) best is to create own ping messages. Current state - sending only pong and not checking response is pathetic.