# Are manual ping messages required to detect WebSocket client and/or server disconnects

Tags: c#, networking, websocket

I'm working with WebSockets, and need both the client and the server to be able to eventually notice if the other party got disconnected.

My impression was that this is automatically handled with ping frames under the covers, which seems to be backed up by similar questions on stackoverflow - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390550/pinging-websocket-server-with-websocket-net-client) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610756/system-net-websockets-ping-pong)

However, [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0#handle-client-disconnects) say

> The server isn't automatically informed when the client disconnects due to loss of connectivity

I don't understand how these bits tie up. If ping/pongs are sent automatically, why would the server not be informed if the clients loses connectivity?

Is the client the one initiating the pings, thereby noticing if no pongs come back &  disconneting/throwing, whereby the server does not automatically throw if it doesn't receive any pings from a client? Or how else would I need to interpret this?

Answer (score 0):

Those questions you linked to may be a little misleading because they appear to be speaking from the perspective of the client, and not the server, which works a little differently.

It is true that the server is not *automatically* informed when a client disconnects from the WebSocket, but you can find out yourself by making another call to .NET Core’s `ReceiveAsync` and checking `CloseStatus`:

> Even if the client will never send messages to the server, you still have to call `ReceiveAsync`. That is, assuming you want to know when the client has disconnected! I found out the hard way that `CloseStatus` does not get updated unless you keep calling `ReceiveAsync`.

Quote is from https://www.codetinkerer.com/2018/06/05/aspnet-core-websockets.html

For example, just because the client calls `webSocket.send(“hello”)` in JavaScript doesn’t mean the server will receive the message. The .NET Core server must make a call to `ReceiveAsync` in order to receive the `hello` message. The same goes for disconnects. The server has to call `ReceiveAsync` to know if the client has disconnected.

As for the client (i.e. JavaScript) knowing if it has lost connection, that’s easy: just put a listener on the WebSocket `close` and/or `error` events.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: Thanks,  that makes sense. Both client and servers continuously call ReceiveAsync() in my case, so that should be covered. I'm still a bit baffled by the Microsoft docs though, as they explicitly speak of "sending" ping, not of ensuring to _receive_ on the connection

Comment: @Bogey sounds like you’re doing it right, just make sure you’re checking the CloseStatus after each call to ReceiveAsync so you know if the connection needs to be disposed

Comment: @Bogey I know what you mean by the official docs being confusing, as they don’t make it clear that you need to make sure to receive. But alas, you do